How to write into excel with npm xlsx in react
I am auto-generating a report that creates an excel file with data formatted and cell colors.
I want to use npm xlsx if possible but it seems difficult to understand, especially that my output report is not a mere table.
Like at cell A1, the name of the report with bold letters.
A2 is like date range.
A3 is some remarks.
A6 to H6 are the table headers.
A7 to say H40 are the data.
And after creating that I want to download it.
